# Different style of Tabs (ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, styles, actionbarsherlock

I want to create two tabs with different styles. What I must do to get such result like in example?

Example:

[image]

And what I have now:

[image]

**TabsActivity**

```
public class TabsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.l_maintab);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_striped);         
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

            BitmapDrawable bgSplit = (BitmapDrawable) 
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_striped_split_img);
            bgSplit.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            getSupportActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(bgSplit);
        }

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager));

        ActionBar.Tab events_tab = bar.newTab().setText("Events");
        ActionBar.Tab volo_tab = bar.newTab().setText("Volunteers");

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(events_tab, EventFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(volo_tab, UserFragment.class, null);

        bar.selectTab(bar.getTabAt(tabnum));
    }
```

**l_maintab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the background that you assign to the tab (usually through styles and themes). Create a style for the tab:

```
<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

I've extended the ActionBarSherlock style so that the only relevant override is the background attribute. In your theme definition, add these to your theme:

```
<item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
```

Then all you need to do is make a drawable resource for each state and include a state-list drawable resource for your background.

EDIT:
If you have two different tab styles:

```
<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_tab_indicator</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOtherTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_other_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Make your app theme, then make a second one extending it:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock...">
    <!-- other theme attributes -->
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.Alternate">
    <!-- Override just the tab style -->
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyOtherTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyOtherTabStyle</item>
</style>
```

In your Manifest, set `android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"` in the `<application>` element. For Activities that need the second tab style, use `android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.Alternate"` in the `<activity>` element.

Comment: But in this way I will create ONE style for all Tabs, instead own style for each tab, yes?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood your question. What you can do is create a second tab style, and then make an alternate theme that extends your current one and only override the `actionBarTabStyle` attribute. Use the second theme for the activity that has the second style of tabs in your manifest.

Comment: Your solution will work if I have one activity per tab. But I have one TabsActivity and one fragment for each tab. Fragments doesn't declared in AndroidManifest.xml that is why I cann't use your solution.

Comment: ActionBar is per Activity. Of you have one Activity, then you have one ActionBar and one set of tabs (and you would use my first solution). Perhaps I still don't understand your situation. If you change fragments by selecting another tab, then why change the style of the tabs? That seems like a confusing user experience.

Comment: "That seems like a confusing user experience" - Yes, but I need to do this. Now, you understand my problem.

Comment: This may or may not be helpful, but try having a discussion with your designer about it and see if there's an alternative that is more unified and/or doesn't require changing the style of ActionBar tabs within the same Activity. Even logically, why would it be necessary? USer will only ever see one style when "Events" is selected and the other style when "Volunteers" is selected, and I've never seen any app doing this.